# How to use leftmark in LaTeX in memoir class

Tags: header-footer, memoir

I am using document class `memoir`. I want too use `\leftmark` to display section headings as headers. Can you give a small sample program how to use `\leftmark` in LaTeX in `memoir`. I read the manual but did not understand it. Following is the program

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{section}{both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
}
\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}


\section*{Introduction}

 same moment it is produced. When you flip a switch, the electric power is there. Behind the scenes, state electricity board employees are hard at work operating and maintaining the comwhich I have learnt at GNDTP 1 in this report. Additional help has been taken from internet which has 

\end{document}
```

Comment: It might be an idea to post what you already have. Plus you might want to read this http://tug.org/pracjourn/2008-2/madsen/. One hint for the manual `\createmark` and have a look at what the second argument for that macro does.

Comment: Please I am not able to understand. give me one sample program where you are able to get section or subsection name as a header. Just a small sample please

Comment: As daleif mentioned, you really need to add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to show your starting point, as "do it for me" questions aren't encouraged on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said it is easy. Please do not make us do your work for you. At least post a minimal example of what you have tried.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\addtopsmarks{headings}{}{
  \createmark{section}{both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
}
\pagestyle{headings}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % provides sample text
\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\kant 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Taking the example of your program. Header with section name has come. But I have put * in front of \section to hide the number of section. When I put * in front of section and run your same given program header showing "Test" disappears. Now what can I do ?

Comment: Well first of all please provide more details about your document. Usually `\section*` does not write to the headers. If no sestions should have numbers why don't you just use `\setsecnumdepth{chapter}` (if chapters should be numbered or just `none` if nothing is to be numbered). And then use normal `\section`. Again, details, details details.

Comment: Thank you very much. \setsecnumdepth{none} removed the numbers and your program solved the problem. Sorry I will put MWE from next time

Comment: Just 1 more doubt. Is there some way to decrease font size of header text and make horizontal line below it. I have put the details above

Comment: See the `memoir` manual. Or the article I already linked to.